Code works in Debug mode but not in release mode (connected to another source of power)


#include "hal_LCD.h"
#include "gpio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

// Define the GPIO pins corresponding to each emotion button
#define JOY_PIN   BIT4 // P1.4
#define SAD_PIN   BIT3 // P1.3
#define ANGRY_PIN BIT6 // P1.6
#define FEAR_PIN  BIT7 // P1.7
#define MALICE_PIN BIT5 // P2.5
#define AMAZE_PIN BIT7 // P2.7

// Define maximum number of synonyms for each emotion
#define MAX_SYNONYMS 5

// Define synonyms for each emotion
const char* joySynonyms[MAX_SYNONYMS] = {"HAPPY", "GLAD", "CHEER", "DELITE", "MIRTH"};
const char* sadSynonyms[MAX_SYNONYMS] = {"GLOOM", "MELAN", "SORROW", "DESOL", "TEARS"};
const char* angrySynonyms[MAX_SYNONYMS] = {"FUROR", "IRATE", "RAGE", "ANGER", "STRESS"};
const char* fearSynonyms[MAX_SYNONYMS] = {"TERROR", "DREAD", "ANX", "ALARM", "PANIC"};
const char* maliceSynonyms[MAX_SYNONYMS] = {"SPITE", "HATE", "VENOM", "MALICE", "SPURN"};
const char* amazeSynonyms[MAX_SYNONYMS] = {"WONDER", "AMAZE", "ASTON", "AWING", "MARVEL"};

// Global variables to hold the display index, button index, and score
int displayIndex = 0;
int buttonIndex = 0;


// Function to display a word on the LCD
void displayWord(const char* word) {
    clearLCD();
    int len = strlen(word);
    if (len <= 3) {
        showChar(word[0], pos1);
        if (len >= 2) {
            showChar(word[1], pos2);
        }
        if (len == 3) {
            showChar(word[0], pos1);
            showChar(word[1], pos2);
            showChar(word[2], pos3);
        }
    } else if (len == 4) {
        showChar(word[0], pos1);
        showChar(word[1], pos2);
        showChar(word[2], pos3);
        showChar(word[3], pos4);
    } else if (len == 5) {
        showChar(word[0], pos1);
        showChar(word[1], pos2);
        showChar(word[2], pos3);
        showChar(word[3], pos4);
        showChar(word[4], pos5);
    } else if (len == 6){
        showChar(word[0], pos1);
        showChar(word[1], pos2);
        showChar(word[2], pos3);
        showChar(word[3], pos4);
        showChar(word[4], pos5);
        showChar(word[5], pos6);
    }
}

// Function to display "START" on the LCD for 3 seconds
void displayStartScreen() {
    clearLCD();
    showChar('S', pos1);
    showChar('T', pos2);
    showChar('A', pos3);
    showChar('R', pos4);
    showChar('T', pos5);
    __delay_cycles(3000000); // Delay for 3 seconds
}

void displayScore(int score) {
    clearLCD();
    showChar('P', pos1);
    showChar('T', pos2);
    showChar('S', pos3);

    int hundreds = score/100;
    int tens = score / 10;
    int units = score % 10;
    showChar(hundreds + '0', pos4);
    showChar(tens + '0', pos4);
    showChar(units + '0', pos5);
    __delay_cycles(4000000);
    WDTCTL = 0; //Trigger watchdog reset
}

// Function to initialize button pins
void initButtonPins() {
    // Set button pins as inputs with internal pull-up resistors
    GPIO_setAsInputPinWithPullUpResistor(GPIO_PORT_P1, JOY_PIN);
    GPIO_setAsInputPinWithPullUpResistor(GPIO_PORT_P1, SAD_PIN);
    GPIO_setAsInputPinWithPullUpResistor(GPIO_PORT_P1, ANGRY_PIN);
    GPIO_setAsInputPinWithPullUpResistor(GPIO_PORT_P1, FEAR_PIN);
    GPIO_setAsInputPinWithPullUpResistor(GPIO_PORT_P2, MALICE_PIN);
    GPIO_setAsInputPinWithPullUpResistor(GPIO_PORT_P2, AMAZE_PIN);
}

// Function to configure interrupts for button pins
void configureButtonInterrupts() {
    // Enable interrupts for each button pin
    GPIO_selectInterruptEdge(GPIO_PORT_P1, JOY_PIN, GPIO_LOW_TO_HIGH_TRANSITION);
    GPIO_selectInterruptEdge(GPIO_PORT_P1, SAD_PIN, GPIO_LOW_TO_HIGH_TRANSITION);
    GPIO_selectInterruptEdge(GPIO_PORT_P1, ANGRY_PIN, GPIO_LOW_TO_HIGH_TRANSITION);
    GPIO_selectInterruptEdge(GPIO_PORT_P1, FEAR_PIN, GPIO_LOW_TO_HIGH_TRANSITION);
    GPIO_selectInterruptEdge(GPIO_PORT_P2, MALICE_PIN, GPIO_LOW_TO_HIGH_TRANSITION);
    GPIO_selectInterruptEdge(GPIO_PORT_P2, AMAZE_PIN, GPIO_LOW_TO_HIGH_TRANSITION);
    GPIO_clearInterrupt(GPIO_PORT_P1, JOY_PIN | SAD_PIN | ANGRY_PIN | FEAR_PIN);
    GPIO_clearInterrupt(GPIO_PORT_P2, MALICE_PIN | AMAZE_PIN);
    GPIO_enableInterrupt(GPIO_PORT_P1, JOY_PIN | SAD_PIN | ANGRY_PIN | FEAR_PIN);
    GPIO_enableInterrupt(GPIO_PORT_P2, MALICE_PIN | AMAZE_PIN);
}

// Function to check if any button is pressed
int isAnyButtonPressed() {
    return GPIO_getInputPinValue(GPIO_PORT_P1, JOY_PIN) ||
           GPIO_getInputPinValue(GPIO_PORT_P1, SAD_PIN) ||
           GPIO_getInputPinValue(GPIO_PORT_P1, ANGRY_PIN) ||
           GPIO_getInputPinValue(GPIO_PORT_P1, FEAR_PIN) ||
           GPIO_getInputPinValue(GPIO_PORT_P2, MALICE_PIN) ||
           GPIO_getInputPinValue(GPIO_PORT_P2, AMAZE_PIN);
}

int main(void)
{
    // Stop watchdog timer
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;
    // Initialize LCD
    Init_LCD();
    displayStartScreen();
    PMM_unlockLPM5();
    // Initialize button pins
    initButtonPins();

    // Enable interrupts for button pins
    configureButtonInterrupts();

    // Enable global interrupts
    __enable_interrupt();

    int score = 0; // Variable to store the score

    while (1)
    {
        // Generate a random number to represent the emotion
        srand(time(NULL)); // Seed the random number generator
        int randomNumber = rand() % 6 + 1; // Generate a random number between 1 and 6

        // Set the display index based on the random number
        switch (randomNumber) {
            case 1:
                displayIndex = 1;
                displayWord(joySynonyms[rand() % MAX_SYNONYMS]);
                break;
            case 2:
                displayIndex = 2;
                displayWord(sadSynonyms[rand() % MAX_SYNONYMS]);
                break;
            case 3:
                displayIndex = 3;
                displayWord(angrySynonyms[rand() % MAX_SYNONYMS]);
                break;
            case 4:
                displayIndex = 4;
                displayWord(fearSynonyms[rand() % MAX_SYNONYMS]);
                break;
            case 5:
                displayIndex = 5;
                displayWord(maliceSynonyms[rand() % MAX_SYNONYMS]);
                break;
            case 6:
                displayIndex = 6;
                displayWord(amazeSynonyms[rand() % MAX_SYNONYMS]);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        // Wait until any button is pressed
        while (!isAnyButtonPressed());

        // Compare displayIndex and buttonIndex to update the score
        if (displayIndex == buttonIndex) {
            score++; // Increment score for correct button press
        }else{
            displayScore(score);
        }
    }
}


// Interrupt service routine for button presses on port 1
#pragma vector = PORT1_VECTOR
__interrupt void Port1_ISR(void) {
    switch (__even_in_range(P1IV, P1IV_P1IFG7)) {
        case P1IV_P1IFG4:
            buttonIndex = 1; // JOY button
            break;
        case P1IV_P1IFG3:
            buttonIndex = 2; // SAD button
            break;
        case P1IV_P1IFG6:
            buttonIndex = 3; // ANGRY button
            break;
        case P1IV_P1IFG7:
            buttonIndex = 4; // FEAR button
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    // Clear the interrupt flag
    P1IFG &= ~(JOY_PIN | SAD_PIN | ANGRY_PIN | FEAR_PIN);
}

// Interrupt service routine for button presses on port 2
#pragma vector = PORT2_VECTOR
__interrupt void Port2_ISR(void) {
    switch (__even_in_range(P2IV, P2IV_P2IFG7)) {
        case P2IV_P2IFG5:
            buttonIndex = 5; // MALICE button
            break;
        case P2IV_P2IFG7:
            buttonIndex = 6; // AMAZE button
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    // Clear the interrupt flag
    P2IFG &= ~(MALICE_PIN | AMAZE_PIN);
}



I am having a struggle with this.
In CCS (Code Composure Studio), in debug mode the above code works fine on my MSP-EXP430FR4133 microcontroller, but when I disconnect it from my pc for debug mode and connect a battery to it with enough voltage it then doesn't do the same thing like as in debug mode.
Any help on this would be appreciated as I am in the process of a project for university.
Hamid
I have tried putting it to release mode but still does the same thing.
What I expect is when a random emotion word is displayed on the screen it sets a variable (displayIndex) to a specific number using a case statement. Then another variable (buttonIndex) is set using the buttons I have on my breadboard. The idea is to compare the to values from the variables in an if statement to add 1 to a score or to end the game and show the points the user has gotten from right button pressed.

Instead of linking to code, please type it out in your question.

I'd guess that variables shared between interrupts and main program are not volatile/atomic.

A common problem is that you are using a "RAM build" where the code is downloaded to RAM instead of flash. In which case the whole program will disappear once you cycle power.

Similarly all those pointer arrays should be declared as const char* const joySynonyms[...] or they will end up in RAM, not flash.

Also you don't appear to have any button debouncing so how is that going to work, debug or release?

I have tested it with a debouce i see no difference but i can add it in easy

I have tried adding the const just before each array definition but it still ends on the correct button press

So is there any way to have it run the same way as the debug mode?

I don't have an answer, but to have the GPIO configuration to take effect, I think you should issue the  PMM_unlockLPM5(); after the configuration. So I'll move it before __enable_interrupt()...maybe this won't change anything, just a try
